# google analytics api - username list and list of access

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

is there any way how to get the list of all usernames for a specific account in GA. And as output it would be shown in Google Spreadsheet. 
Moreover, can you find all properties/profiles using GA API the user is having access to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [User Permissions APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions) to list all the users and associated permissions for a particular [Account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/list), [Property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webpropertyUserLinks/list) or [view](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileUserLinks/list).

```
  properties = analytics.management().webpropertyUserLinks().list(
      accountId='123456',
      webPropertyId='UA-123456-1'
  ).execute()
```

For your inverse question of requesting all the accounts, properties and views to which a user has access, you can use the [account summaries API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) to list all the account details for the [Authenticated user](https://developers.google.com/accounts/).

```
account_summaries = analytics.management().accountSummaries().list().execute()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, is there any way how to get a list of all accounts, properties, views with their users at once?
Thanks.

Comment: Each level has its own user permissions and will need to be queried independatnly, a user can have access at the account level: analytics.management().accountUserLinks().list(...)  or a user might have permissions at the we property level: analytics.management().webpropertyUserLinks().list(...) or a user might have permissions at the view level: analytics.management().profileUserLinks().list(...) Each level needs to be queried independently.